# Content is overflowing in other sizes - Bootstrap full width and height pages -

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

StackOverflow's been helping me a lot, but now it's the first time i ask. I'm making a website with bootstrap. In Desktop it is fine, but when i test it on my iphone 4 (or chrome's F12) its contents does not fit.

here it goes

CSS

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* MY CUSTOM CSS*/
/* ------------Bootstrap---------------*/

@media (max-width: @screen-xs) {
    body{font-size: 10px;}
container-fluid fill{
  width:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
 

}
.titulo-inicial{
 
font-size:2em;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm) {
    body{font-size: 14px;}
 .fill{
  width:100%;
       height:auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;

}
.titulo-inicial{
 margin-top:20px;
font-size:2em;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

}

.container-fluid{
padding:0; 
}
body, html {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}


/* MENU SUPERIOR*/
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.fill{
  width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;

}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.brand{
 color:#fff;
 margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    float: left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu .simbolo{
 height:46px;
 width:46px;
 background:url(../img/logo-franken.png);
 margin:5px auto 3px auto;
 /*float:left;*/
  
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu .logotipo{
 float:left;
 color:#fff;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:lighter;
 
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(8, 3, 3, 1);
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
 margin:auto;
 
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default{
margin-left:0; 
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 margin-left:10px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(173, 173, 173, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(116, 0, 158, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #080303;
}

/****************HOME****************/

/*-------------DIVs------------/







/* ------------ HEADERS    ----------*/
.titulo-inicial{
 margin-top:20px;
font-size:5em;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}


/* -------------- PARAGRAFOS -------------*/
.texto-inicial{
 margin-top:20px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:1.5em; 
}


/******************* FIM HOME *************************/




/****************SERVICOS****************/

/*-------------DIVs------------*/


.cont-servicos{
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
}




/* ------------ HEADERS    ----------*/
.titulo-servicos{
 margin-top:50px;
font-size:2em;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#306;
}

h2{
 margin-top:20px;
 color:#306;
 font-size:1.5em;
 line-height:20px;
 
}


/* -------------- PARAGRAFOS -------------*/
.texto-servicos{
max-width:550px;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
margin-bottom:5%;
color:#333;
 
}

.desc-servicos{
color:#333; 
}


/******************* FIM SERVICOS*************************/

/**************** PORTFOLIO ****************/

/*-------------DIVs------------*/



/*-------------CAROUSSEL------------*/

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   overflow:hidden;

}

/* ------------ HEADERS    ----------*/
.titulo-portfolio{

font-size:2em;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#306;
}

h2{
 margin-top:20px;
 color:#306;
 font-size:1.5em;
 line-height:20px;
 
}


/* -------------- PARAGRAFOS -------------*/
.texto-servicos{
max-width:550px;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
margin-bottom:5%;
color:#333;
 
}

.desc-servicos{
color:#333; 
}


/******************* FIM PORTFOLIO Protocolo unimed 1172425*************************/



/**************** ORCAMENTO ****************/





/******************* FIM ORCAMENTO *************************/

/**************** Contato ****************/





/******************* FIM Contato *************************/

/* ------------ COMUM ---------------*/
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top:104px;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}


#logo-img {
 width:70px;
 height: 40px;
 margin:auto;
}


#home {
 background:#000;
}

#servicos {
 background:#CCC;
}

#portfolio {
 background:#F2F2F2;
}
#freelance {
 background:yellow;
}

#contato {
 background:purple;
}


.fullscreen-bg {
   position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
   /* z-index: -100;*/
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Company</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:700,400italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

<!-- Viewport Bootstrap -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid container-full">
      <div class="simbolo"></div>
      <!--<div class="logotipo">My Company</div>--> 
      
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="brand visible-sm visible-xs" href="#">My Company</div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Quem somos</a> </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#servicos">O que fazemos</a> </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
        <!--<li><a href="#">Cases</a> </li>-->
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#orcamento">Orçamento</a> </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contato">Contato</a> </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#blog">Blog</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="home" class="container-fluid fill">
  <div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
      <source src="vids/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="titulo-inicial"> My Company </h1>
        <p class="texto-inicial"> LoMy Companyr sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor. Sed iaculis posuere diam ut cursus. <em>Morbi commodo sodales nisi id sodales. Proin consectetur, nisi id commodo imperdiet, metus nunc consequat lectus, id bibendum diam velit et dui.</em> Proin massa magna, vulputate nec bibendum nec, posuere nec lacus. <small>Aliquam mi erat, aliquam vel luctus eu, pharetra quis elit. Nulla euismod ultrices massa, et feugiat ipsum consequat eu.</small> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="servicos" class="container-fluid fill">
  <div class="row cont-servicos" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="titulo-servicos"> O que fazemos </h1>
      <p class="texto-servicos "> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor. Sed iaculis posuere diam ut cursus. </p>
      <div class="row desc-servicos">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2><img src="img/ico-dg.png"> Design Gráfico </h2>
          <p> Identidade Visual (Logotipo), Folders, Cartazes 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2><img src="img/ico-wd.png"> Web Design </h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2><img src="img/ico-de.png"> Design Editorial </h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row desc-servicos">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2><img src="img/ico-ev.png"> Edição de Vídeo </h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2><img src="img/ico-3d.png"> Renderização 3D </h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2><img src="img/ico-ad.png"> Assessoria em Design </h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid fill" style="padding:0;">
  <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="overflow:hidden;"> 
    
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    
    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active"> 
        <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
        <div class="fill2" style="background-image:url(../site-franken-OLD/img/portfolio/1.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Caption 1</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item"> 
        <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
        <div class="fill2" style="background-image:url(../site-franken-OLD/img/portfolio/2.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Caption 2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item"> 
        <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
        <div class="fill2" style="background-image:url(../site-franken-OLD/img/portfolio/3.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>Caption 3</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Controls --> 
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> <span class="icon-prev"></span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="icon-next"></span> </a> </header>
</div>
<div id="orcamento" class="container-fluid fill">
  <div class="row cont-servicos" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="titulo-portfolio"> Orçamento </h1>
      <p class="texto-servicos "> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/jnu5zm70/)   what you want ? if yes then add `.container-fluid{overflow:hidden;}` to your styles.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sort of. As you see, the content of Servicos is hidden. The section should enlarge vertically to have it all =~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/jnu5zm70/3/)

Your CSS

```
.fill{
    width:100%;  
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
}
```

Just remove `height:100%;` from this.

Suggestion In using Boostrap:

The default format for `containers`, `row` and `col*'s` is

```
<div class="container"><!-- container-fluid can be used in this div -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><!--Your content that takes 12 columns goes here--></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><!--Your content that takes 4 columns goes here--></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><!--Your content that takes 8 columns goes here--></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Inside a `row` sum of all columns must be less than or equal to 12. if it greater than 12 then the  last element(div ,span etc) in the row will be visible below the other elements of same row.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) something very simple that you can use. Or you can refer this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839792/bootstrap-3-custom-css-class-depending-of-devices)link.

Comment: Excatly, right. As you see it, I've put  @media (max-width: @screen-xs)

but it does not work. =/